# Command history in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh

Currently I have zsh set up in such a way that command history is shared between all sessions immediately.

Say I have a terminal emulator open with two tabs, each with a zsh session, A1 and A2. If I enter ls -la in A1, and then go to A2 and press up arrow key, I will see ls -la in the command prompt.

I would like to change it so sessions don't share the command history with each other although when you start new session it gets all the previous history from all sessions before it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the available [options to control history](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History). I think you want

```
setopt append_history no_inc_append_history no_share_history
```

This is the default zsh setup, by the way.

You can save the history explicitly at any point with `fc -AI` and merge it back in with `fc -RI`.

Comment: I would argue that `setopt inc_append_history` would be indicated by the OP, since he wants new sessions to access "history from all sessions before it," which includes currently open sessions, not just closed sessions; this means that they need to write to the history file immediately as commands are run (right before actually), which is what this option does.  With `noincappendhistory`, the OP will open a new shell, and not see commands from currently open ones; they will have to close those first before opening the new session.